# jQuery text to input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple layout with a textblock and one `<a>`, like:

> text1 [edit](/#)

When I click on the `<a>`, I want this textblock to become text input. How is that possible with jQuery?

Comment: I have answered a similar question, take a look to: 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/28360984/442883

Comment: I have answered a similar question, take a look to: 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/28360984/442883

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jQuery [`replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().replaceWith("<input />");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Dqkyg/1/

---

Furthermore, you can fill the textbox with the text outside the link like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var txt = $(".text").html();
        $(".text").replaceWith("<input value='" + txt + "' />");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Dqkyg/5/

---

The following will replace the edit with Save & Cancel options:

```
<div>
    <span class="text">testing</span> <a href='#'>test</a>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var txt = $(".text").html();
        $(".text").replaceWith("<input value='" + txt + "' />");
        $(this).replaceWith("<a href='#'>Save</a> | <a href='#'>Cancel</a>");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Dqkyg/6/

Comment: Sounds like he wants to replace the whole block, not just the `a` (`$(this).parent().replace('<input />');`?)

Comment: @RoyiNamir - Sorry syntax error. Corrected. Was too eager to test!

Comment: I think he wants to keep the anchor. So he will have to wrap the textblock in a tag (span, div, p, whatever). Then : http://jsfiddle.net/Dqkyg/2/

Comment: Cheers @CyStack, I've added that to my alternative

Comment: In fact, I need textblock to be replaced with input, and 'edit' link to be replaced with 2 others: 'save' and 'cancel' :) I think I can figure the rest by myself, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of plugins that you can use... No need to reinvent the wheel

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable

Comment: of course ther're oplenty of, but sometimes it's just easier to write three lines of code.

Comment: @llya yeah but that doesn't include the code to save the input and return it to the server to persist (assuming you want to do that.... which you probably do)

Answer (score 1):

Hmm ... ur a bit unclear... but
http://jsfiddle.net/mMYrf/4/

```
<div class="dataGrid">
    <span>test</span>
    <a href="#">edit</a>
</div>
```

And

```
$('.dataGrid a').click( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var EditGrid = $(this).parent().children('span');
        var DataTxt = EditGrid.text();
        var InputHtml = '<input type=text" value="'+DataTxt +'" />';

        $(this).text('Save?');
        EditGrid.html(InputHtml);
});
```

Comment: What's wrong with your jsfiddle ? that not belong to this question.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="editable">This is the content.</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.editable').each(function() {
            var a = $('<a href="#">edit</a>');
            (function(link, parent) {
                link.click(function() {
                    link.remove();
                    var textField = $('<textarea/>').val(parent.html());
                    parent.replaceWith(textField);
                    delete parent, link;
                });
            })(a, $(this));
            $(this).append(" ").append(a);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/BnH29/