# jquery/javascript convert a plain text message into a text input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-interface

i've got the following request:

create a plain text field that transforms into an text input element when clicking on an edit trigger. When leaving the input element the text will be stored in the database and the field is transformed back into a plain text field with the new content. When ESC is pressed in the input the recent value is restored. To do this i use the following code:

```
<div id="value"><span id="text">some text</span></div>
<div id="trigger">[EDIT]</div>
<div style="display: none;" id="storage">
  <input type="text" id="input" value="some text"/>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#trigger').click(function() {
    var t = $('#text').detach();
    var e = $('#input').detach();

    $('#storage').append(t);
    $('#value').append(e);
    e.focus();
  });

  $('#input').blur(function() {
    var t = $('#text').detach();
    var e = $('#input').detach();

    if (t.text() != e.val()) {
      $.getJSON(...);
    }

    $('#storage').append(e);
    $('#value').append(t);
  });

  $('#input').keyup(function(event) {

    if (event.which == 27) {
      $('#input').val($('#text').text());
      $('#input')[0].blur();
    }

  });

</script>
```

Thanks to @nnnnnn this now works. But is there maybe a simpler way to implement this using some preexisting API functions?

thanks very much.

Comment: Shouldn't `${'#someActiveInput'}.focus();` be `$('#someActiveInput').focus();`?

Comment: maybe it's a little too late (12 hours at work already) but i can't see a difference between my version and yours? Nevertheless - this was only an example how it works - so this is not the problematic part ;)

Comment: Curly braces vs. parenthesis. Not that this is a solution, just a question about whether this way a typo or intentional.

Comment: definitively too late - yes you're right - it have to be parenthesis - updated it.

Comment: I know this isn't directly addressing your issue, but the `contenteditable` attribute will make non-form elements interactive like text areas, and I believe automatically fire the blur and focus events from the UA, so jquery should catch them.  If having a trigger is important (you want a visual control, etc), you could simply have the control give focus to the element with `contenteditable` set to true.  It's supported in all major non-mobile browsers (IE6+, even).

Comment: _"The problem with this is, that the .blur() obviously does not remove the focus from the input but correctly calls the blur() event handler."_ If you want to actually remove focus try `$('#input')[0].blur()` - that is, call the native [`.blur()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.blur)`.

Comment: @nnnnnn - long question short answer: $('#input')[0].blur() did the trick. Thanks very much! Maybe there are nevertheless any suggestions how to solve this request a more sexy way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use jquery editable here is a link

for demo:
http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/default.html

for plugin home page
http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable

Answer (score 0):

I developed a plugin that do what you need:

[$.convertTo](https://github.com/rodrigoSaladoAnaya/jqueryConvertTo)

I hope it will be helpful, regards.